# Showing that $(1 + \sqrt{3})$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ but that $(2)$ is not a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here is the question I want to solve:

Showing that $(1 + \sqrt{3})$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ but that $(2)$ is not a prime ideal.

**A HINT GIVEN TO ME:**

For the first part I was given this hint:

Let $I$ be a maximal ideal containing $(1 + \sqrt{3})$ then use that every ideal of  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is principal but then I know that every maximal ideal is prime by a lemma. does that prove that $(1 + \sqrt{3})$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$? But I do not understand why we should have that $(1 + \sqrt{3})$ be a principle ideal first?

For the second part, $(2)$ is not a prime ideal. I was given this hint:

Use the Norm function and here is my trial:

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}],$ suppose $2R$ is a prime ideal. Then we have $(\sqrt{3} + 1)(\sqrt{3} - 1) = 3 -1 = 2 \in 2R.$ Now suppose $(\sqrt{3} + 1) \in 2R$ then using the norm function we should have $N((\sqrt{3} + 1)) = N(2)N(c)$ for some $c,$ but $N(2) = 4$ and  N((\sqrt{3} + 1)) = 2 but 4 does not divide 2. Same argument can be used for  $(\sqrt{3} - 1).$

Could anyone check if my solutions are correct or no please? and if not, I want to know the correct solution please?

Comment: For the second part, your factorization $2 = (\sqrt{3} + 1)(\sqrt{3} - 1)$ shows that a product of two elements $a, b$ can be in $(2)$ even when neither of the factors $a, b$ are. What does that tell you about primality?

Comment: @RiversMcForge it tells me that $(2)$ is not prime ..... correct?

Comment: @RiversMcForge what about my first part?